# Storing lists of lists in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to store and then display some data in Python 3. I believe the data types i am trying to store / use is a dict of dicts of lists. But I am not 100% sure. I would like to print each variable as a separate entity all at the same time. My assumption is that is will require a combination of for loops

I will give a simplified example which will hopefully help.

I have this information about fruits at supermarkets.

```
- Tesco 
  - Apples  
    - Cooking Apples
    - Granny Smiths
    - Gala
  - Oranges
    - Blood Orange
    - Mandarin Orange
- Asda 
  - Pineapples 
    - Cavendish
    - Burro 
  - Oranges    
    - Blood Orange
    - Tangerine
- Lidl 
  - Apples 
    - Gala 
    - Cooking Apples
  - Mangoes
    - Chaunsa
    - Badami
    - Kesar
```

I would like to store this information and then display it back in a similar format.

Comment: Surely it depends on what you want to *do* with this data. If all you want to do is display it, just store it in one big string and be done with it. Your question is too vague (and also opinion-based) to answer. Provide more details if you want an informative answer.

Comment: @JohnColeman I understand where you are coming on, The purpose of the data is to create a dropdown system. So i need to print each variable as a separate entity

Comment: for storing, I'd just look into saving json files.  There is also a pretty print option, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering the full answer to my question is the following:

To Input the data: 
Credit to 'zipa'.

```
data = {'Tesco': {'Apples': ['Cooking Apples',
                             'Granny Smiths',
                             'Gala'],
                  'Oranges': ['Blood Orange',
                              'Mandarin Orange']
                 },
        'Asda': {'Pineapples': ['Cavendish',
                                'Burro'],
                 'Oranges': ['Blood Orange',
                             'Tangerine']
                 },
        'Lidl': {'Apples': ['Cooking Apples',
                            'Gala'],
                 'Mangoes': ['Chaunsa',
                             'Badami',
                             'Kesar']}
        }
```

And to get it out:

```
    for Supermarket in data:
...     print(Supermarket)
...     for fruit in data[Supermarket]:
...             print(fruit)
...             for type in data[Supermarket][fruit]:
...                     print(type)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, and your example could look like this:

```
data = {'Tesco': {'Apples': ['Cooking Apples',
                             'Granny Smiths',
                             'Gala'],
                  'Oranges': ['Blood Orange',
                              'Mandarin Orange']
                 },
        'Asda': {'Pineapples': ['Cavendish',
                                'Burro'],
                 'Oranges': ['Blood Orange',
                             'Tangerine']
                 },
        'Lidl': {'Apples': ['Cooking Apples',
                            'Gala'],
                 'Mangoes': ['Chaunsa',
                             'Badami',
                             'Kesar']}
        }
```

But, as stated in comments, it really depends on what you want to do with this data.

Comment: That works perfectly for the storing aspect. But how would u print each variable as a separate entity ?

Comment: @KirkmanJ for `Tesco` you'd use `data['Tesco']` and get its contents.

Comment: Yes that does work, but how would u get all the data back. I assume u would use a combination of for loops

Comment: thank you, your solution helped me a great deal and i managed to figure out how to get the data out.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {}
data["Tesco"] = {}
data["Tesco"]["Apples"] = ["Cooking Apples", "Granny Smiths","Gala"]
data["Tesco"]["Oranges"] = ["Blood Orange", "Mandarin Orange"]

data["Asda"] = {}
data["Asda"]["Pineapples "] = ["Cavendish", "Burro"]
data["Asda"]["Oranges"] = ["Blood Orange", "Tangerine"]

data["Lidl"] = {}
data["Lidl"]["Apples  "] = ["Gala ", "Cooking Apples"]
data["Lidl"]["Mangoes"] = ["Chaunsa", "Badami","Kesar"]

print(data)
```

Comment: printing data will print the whole thing. Which is a starting point. How would u print each variable as a separate entity

Comment: @KirkmanJ `print(data["Tesco"])` will give only "Tesco" Supermarket and `print(data["Tesco"]["Apples"])` will give apples in Tesco Supermarket and `print(data["Tesco"]["Apples"][0])` gives first element of Apples.